# Getting disk space error, but enough disk space is available

Tags: asp.net, diskspace, quota

I am experiencing a problem with a website.
Originally the Access database file got lost, and started causing 500 errors on the website because it could not find the database file.

I found a backup of the database and copied it back to the file folder and got a "out of disk space error".

I deleted some pictures in a different directory of the same website to free some space and was then able to get the database file copied back to the directory it belongs in.

When trying to copy the pictures back I receive the disk space error again.

The drive does not have any quotas and the drive is formatted as NTFS.

It seems to me like a 100MB limit is being placed on this site, but I cannot find where.

Some information:

- Operating system: Windows Server 2003 R2
- C drive free space : 508GB
- C drive properties : Quota is disabled [not ticked]
- Website directory : c:\myhostedsite\something.org.za\www\
- Asp.net version 1.1.4322

Error message:

> Error Copying File or Folder Cannot copy XXXXXXX: There is not enough
>   free disk space. Delete one or more files to free disk space, and then
>   try again. To free space on this drive by delegating old or
>   unnecessary files,click Disk Cleanup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems it was a quota issue, but not a quota on the hard drive.

On the server you have to go:

```
Start->
Programs->
Administrative Tools->
File Server Resource Manager
```

Open the Quota Management tab on the left side.
Select Quotas

The website I was having trouble with appeared in the list.
It had a quota of 100MB set

Increasing the quota worked!

Decreasing the quota back to 100MB after the files were copied back breaks the site again.

So the quota has to be left bigger than the size of the directory.

Thank you to everyone that might have been searching the answer for me.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted by ticking the empty V icon to the left so the question is marked as "solved".